# Gitlab-runner local build - login from non TTY device

Tags: docker, gitlab

I'm trying to build my project locally using gitlab-runner on Linux.

```
docker-build:
  stage: build
  image: docker:latest
  script:
    - docker login -u "gitlab-ci-token" -p "$CI_JOB_TOKEN" $CI_REGISTRY # user "gitlab-ci-token" is automatically created by GitLab
    - docker build -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" target/
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
```

Unfortunately my attempts end with error about "docker login" not being able to perform interactive login from non-TTY device.

```
$ gitlab-ci-multi-runner exec docker --docker-privileged docker-build
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.11.1 (a67a225)
  on  ()
Using Docker executor with image docker:latest ...
Starting service docker:dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:dind ...
Waiting for services to be up and running...
Pulling docker image docker:latest ...
Running on runner--project-1-concurrent-0 via vanqyard...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/project-1'...
done.
Checking out 70187b2d as docker-basic-conf...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Checking cache for docker-build/docker-basic-conf...
Successfully extracted cache
$ docker login -u "gitlab-ci-token" -p "$CI_JOB_TOKEN" $CI_REGISTRY
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
FATAL: exit code 1
```

My question is has anybody stumbled upon this issue and how to succesfunlly perform build?

Comment: It shouldn't go into interactive mode since you're providing credentials in the command. Are you sure about those double quotes around `gitlab-ci-token` and `$CI_JOB_TOKEN`?. Maybe the credentials are misinterpreted because of those and the login falls back to interactive mode???

Comment: Getting rid of quotes gives "flag needs an argument: 'p' in -p", so I'm guessing the use of quotes is correct.

Answer (score 86):

Probably not linked to the problem here, but some people might encounter the exact same message when trying a `docker login` from a Linux like terminal on Windows such as **Git bash** or **Docker quickstart terminal** or even **Cygwin**.

The trick here is to use `winpty docker login`

Comment: I had trouble with Linux like terminal (Git Bash), I switched to PowerShell and it worked, no `non TTY device` error.

Comment: After using "winpty docker login" a "com.docker.cli.exe" process runs endlessly (with the login paramters). After calling login several times (as part of a script) I have dozen of "com.docker.cli.exe" processes in the task manager. Can someone tell me why they don't terminate?

Answer (score 55):

Most likely you did not specify the variables `$CI_JOB_TOKEN` and `$CI_REGISTRY` for the project you are working on. Note that variables are *not shared* and are only set *per project*!

That's also why you encounter the error message

> "flag needs an argument: 'p' in -p"

when you try to do the docker login without the quotes, **which is the right way** because otherwise `$CI_JOB_TOKEN` is not recognized as a variable, but it is simply a string consisting of two quotes, a dollar sign and the sequence of chars "CI_JOB_TOKEN".

Assuming your variables are not set and you try to execute the command

```
docker login -u "gitlab-ci-token" -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
```

the variables are evaluated and your command essentially looks like that:

```
docker login -u "gitlab-ci-token" -p
```

The `-p` flag is not followed by a password and for that reason docker tries to initialize an interactive login.

You can verify this by trying to output your variables when you include the command `echo $CI_JOB_TOKEN` in your .gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: This was the issue for me. I set the variables in my project but there is an open issue where they are not actually used by the runner and they are empty https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/31929

Comment: As a note to my future self and others, I fix this in Gitlab by creating a deploy_token named "gitlab-deploy-token" with "read_registry" scope and this resolves the problem using dark magic interactions inside Gitlab code

Answer (score 51):

I had the same issue, but for a different cause than those already listed in here.

This is my gitlab-ci command:

```
docker login "${AZURE_ACR_URL}" -u "${AZURE_ACR_ACCOUNT}" -p "${AZURE_ACR_PASSWORD}"
```

My pipeline was running fine on the master branch, but not on other branches. Why? Because I defined the AZURE_ACR_PASSWORD variable via the settings/ci_cd feature, with the "protected" flag. After reading what this protected flag means I understood why my AZURE_ACR_PASSWORD variable could not be seen in the command:

> This variable will be passed only to pipelines running on protected
>   branches and tags

Comment: Yes, I just encountered this as well, pretty confusing.

Comment: yes, the branches must be protected. I tried and this solved my problem but also other problem is that, docker login from cli does not work if it has special characters. So set your password alphanumeric. Don't know if some special characters are allowed

Comment: Same problem here, ENV VARs were not visible in release/* branches, although I assumed, that release/* are automatically "protected" branches in gitlab.

Answer (score 38):

*Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device* is your typical **red herring** message.
You have to look beyond the message, or rather, *before*. It wants to use interactive login as a fallback solution, because the previous login **failed**. Just like in Unix when your ssh2 auth attempt is rejected. It then prompts for username/password. Except that for emulation of Unix terminals it may fail.

The general answer to this is:
Review each of your parameters, in your command line, and make sure it is what you think it is. A trick is to precede your overall command line with **echo**, so as to resolve all variables...

Comment: This is an underrated answer.

Comment: When adding a secret variable to Azure DevOps Pipelines the add screen says you can access the secret like this ${env:SP_PASSWD}.  The non secrets are accessible this way and the secrets can be accessed like this $(SP_PASSWD).

Answer (score 12):

Reading how protected variables are working solved it for me. I need to perform this action inside a protected branch since I also protected my variables.

If you are not using a protected branch better remove protected variables and try again.

Answer (score 5):

For those who are trying to ssh to a remote host for deploying a docker image via gitlab-ci:

Some variables like `$CI_DEPLOY_USER` `$CI_DEPLOY_PASSWORD` `CI_JOB_TOKEN` and others are not been sent through ssh to the remote server because they are not shared vars.

You need to create a deploy token via config >> repository >> deploy token. This applies for your group or for a specific project.

Then create 2 variables on the project or group via configs >> ci /cd >> variables. The names could be `MASTER_DEPLOY_USER` and `MASTER_DEPLOY_TOKEN`

Then you could login like following

```
deploy-development:
  stage: deploy-development
  image: kroniak/ssh-client
  only:
    - my_development_branch
  before_script:
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$YOUR_SERVER_SSH_PRIV_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
  script:
    - ssh-keygen -R $YOUR_REMOTE_HOST || true
    # login to docker on auth machine with deploy credentials
    - >
      ssh root@${YOUR_REMOTE_HOST}
      "docker login -u $MASTER_DEPLOY_USER -p $MASTER_DEPLOY_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY"
```

Make sure you define also the other needed variables like `YOUR_REMOTE_HOST` and `YOUR_SERVER_SSH_PRIV_KEY`.

Comment: as a note to my future self, I needed to trigger a new pipeline run for the new deploy token to be taken into account, (restarting the deploy job was not enough)

Answer (score 4):

For those that are using variables that are set in settings of GitLab CI/CD, unmark the options protected and masked.
Optionally simply unmarking protected works fine without masked unchecked as well.

This will figure out the docker login problem.

Comment: Exactly my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to log into one registry, you can get the token (from looking at .docker/config.json after a console login or sometimes via the registry itself in the case of Artifactory). Then just echo the results to .docker/config.json

```sh
echo '{ "auths": { "https://awesome_docker_repsitory.com": { "auth": "c4ajLWdpqGxhYi3xYsQ6qVa4aUefY0xbd1t6dtc4YnQ3y2DYTDoOWONx", "email": "bitbucket@foo.bar" } } }' > ~/.docker/config.json"
```

This performs the same action as the docker login (if you don't have a docker credential helper that is).

Answer (score 2):

use this bit of code instead for your docker login:

```bash
echo $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD | docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER $CI_REGISTRY --password-stdin
```

Answer (score 1):

`CI` script fail on docker login. Check if your script have access to $variables.

The issue might be because of protected and not protected branches and variables correlation.

thanks to [pievee](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/error-cannot-perform-an-interactive-login-from-a-non-tty-device/59936) and [greg-witczak](https://github.com/JanMikes/gitlab-ci-push-to-gcr/issues/2#issue-552452892)

I removed protection from variable.

Answer (score 0):

Although I didn't get this error for git-lab, I got it while pulling a different image.

The issue was with using git bash on Windows. Switch to PowerShell prompt and then try the following:

```
docker login
```

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me for **Docker 1.13** ( Rhel-7.8 ):

1. Create a file with your password / ECR key
2. use command
   `docker login --username AWS -p 'cat /data/user/ecr/key' registry-url.amazonaws.com`

**Note:**   *In step 2 please replace `'` with ` while using the command*

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was trying to connect to an AWS-Repo.

```
aws ecr-public get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin public.ecr.aws/XYZ
```

After reading the other answers i just ran the first part of the command:

```
aws ecr-public get-login-password --region us-east-1
```

This resulted in a new Error:

```
"...is not authorized to perform: sts:GetServiceBearerToken..."
```

This error message was used as the password and therefore did not work. So don't get misdirected by the error and search for the root cause.

For AWS-User:
I added the following two Permissions:

```
AWSKeyManagementServicePowerUser, AWSCodeArtifactAdminAccess
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `'` let variables not work

```bash
ssh xxx@xxx 'docker login ${REGISTRY} -u ${REGISTRY_USER} -p ${REGISTRY_PASSWORD} && dosomething'
```

So, you should not use `'`. There are many ways to reach it.

Answer (score -1):

if your here because your getting the error in git hubs workflows (actions). the easiest way to login is the docker login-action step:
https://github.com/marketplace/actions/docker-login#github-packages-docker-registry

```
-   name: Login to GitHub Packages Docker Registry
    uses: docker/login-action@v1
    with:
      registry: docker.pkg.github.com
      username: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
      password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

or for windows build agents:

```
-   name: Login
    shell: pwsh
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    run: echo $env:GITHUB_TOKEN | docker login https://docker.pkg.github.com -u ${env:GITHUB_ACTOR} --password-stdin
```

Comment: how is that relevant for the question being asked? This is gitlab, not github. So no, I'm not here because of github actions.

Comment: Sorry my comment didn't help you. As the other answers implies this is a generic error and can ocour in multiple places. so searching for the error message might get you here. Additionally the ` echo $env:GITHUB_TOKEN | docker..` approuch might work everywere

Answer (score -11):

Try this. `docker login -u Username -p Password`

It worked for me.