# Gitlab: docker login via token fails

Tags: docker, token, gitlab

I'm trying to use gitlab CI runner, but I do get this error trying to login with tokens.

```
$ docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.26/info: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied). Using system default: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.26/auth: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

I can do a `docker login` via prompt with my user/pwd, but not with the token. What am I doing wrong?

The runner is a shell runner.

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

before_script:
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question but here's a related query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43248455/gitlab-runner-local-build-login-from-non-tty-device

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help :-(

Comment: Have you add your user to Docker group?

Comment: @JoséAntonioLópez Thanks. It was that simple...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gitlab-runner was not set as user of docker group

```
sudo usermod -aG docker gitlab-runner
```